# Yank/select until delimiter in different lines

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

From the following text:

```
variable1 = 'example'
foo = 'foo'
barett = 'ver'
```

I would like to yank (or visually select, if possible) the content of each line until the `=` sign:

```
variable1
foo
barett
```

That is: "yank/visually select the contents of the following lines, stopping the yanking/selection in each line as soon as an `=` character is found"

If I were dealing with a single line it would be simple> from the beginning of the line: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

But I have no clue how to do this with multiple lines (and visual block won't help since I don't want the same number of characters from each line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but you could try this mapping:

```
xno my y'>pV']:s/=.*//<cr>gvd
```

To use it, you would visually select your lines, then hit `my`. It should write the text before the `=` character on each line of your selection, inside the unnamed register.

Here's what it does:

- `y` yanks the selection
- `'>` moves the cursor to the last line of the selection
- `p` puts the unnamed register, where currently the last yanked text is
- `V` goes into visual line mode
- `']` moves the end of the selection down to the last line of the last text on which you performed an operation (here the yanking)
- `:s/=.*//<cr>` removes everything after the `=` character, on each line of the selection
- `gv` reselects the last selection
- `d` deletes it

Comment: I'm giving it a go. Maybe instead of the last `yu` I could use `d`? Otherwise the `u`undoes the `:s/=.*//<cr>`, not the pasting.

Comment: @user2891462 Indeed, you're right, `d` should work too, and it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

- ytx – yank from the current cursor position up to and before the
  character (til x)
- yfx – yank from the current cursor position up to
  and including the character (find x)

Comment: Thanks Natan. I now how to do it in a single line (I mention it in the question), what I wanted to know is how to do it on multiple lines at the same time. Check out @user547381's answer for something which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work without pasting/deleting:

```
:let @a = ''
[visually select, or don't to use the whole file]
:global/=/normal! 0"Ayt=
```

1. Empty an alphabetic register (`qaq` works for this too)
2. On each line (possibly in the range) matching `=`, do `0"Ayt=`, which appends to the `a` register as it yanks.